# WPF Listview

Tags: wpf, listview

How to create a GridView like view to the WPF ListView if i dont know the Column names at the design time because the collection will be created at runtime and the collection will be of type DataTable and it may contain a no.of columns.I can do it with WPF DataGrid but i want to achieve this with WPF ListView and I want to Achieve this without code behind.

Answer (score 1):

You can add columns dynamically to a ListView by using Attached Properties. Check out this article on the **CodeProject** it explains exactly that...

[WPF DynamicListView - Binding to a DataMatrix](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DynamicListView.aspx)